# Javascript Multi-translation website with microsoft translator API

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am quiet new with all this and this is my first question asked on StackOverflow.
My issue is with finding a way to translate the same word into multiple languages at the same time through the use of the Microsoft translator API.

In the HTML there are different divs, which define some rain effects and inside them the word translated should appear in the allocated output text-area.

```
<div class="translater-text">
    <textarea id="user" placeholder=""></textarea>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button id="clear" class="btnOutline">Clear</button>
        <button id="translate" class="btnOutline">Translate</button>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- German -->

<div class="rain">
    <div class="drop"></div>
    <div class="waves">
    <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="splash">
        <div class="words">
            <span>
                <div class="output">
                <textarea id="output" placeholder="" readonly></textarea>
            </div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="output">
    <textarea id="output" placeholder=""readonly></textarea>
    <span> </span>
    </div>

    <div class="particles">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>



<!-- Spanish -->

<div class="rain">
    <div class="drop"></div>
    <div class="waves">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="splash">
        <div class="words">
            <span>
                <div class="output">
                <textarea id="output" placeholder="" readonly></textarea>
            </div>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="particles">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

where the javascript needs to translate the text entered and place it inside the #output textarea for any language in the code.

```
const settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://microsoft-translator-text.p.rapidapi.com/translate?to=de&api-version=3.0&profanityAction=NoAction&textType=plain",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "x-rapidapi-key": "5456c22092mshe1f307f4dc62e1fp1169c8jsn7394b540a161",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "microsoft-translator-text.p.rapidapi.com"
    },
    "processData": false,
    "data": '[{ \"Text": \"Something.\" }]'
};



$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(settings.data);
});
```

Please let me know if more info is needed. Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

> My issue is with finding a way to translate the same word into
> multiple languages at the same time through the use of the Microsoft
> translator API.

Ok, so this is your main concern I believe. And I'm assuming that you're using [Microsoft Translator Text API](https://rapidapi.com/microsoft-azure-org-microsoft-cognitive-services/api/microsoft-translator-text/) on RapidAPI Hub.

The `POST` Translate request of this particular API translates to multiple languages simultaneously by repeating the `to` parameter in the query string.

You just need to change the `URL` of your request in the code that you posted above to something like this:

```
"url": "https://microsoft-translator-text.p.rapidapi.com/translate?to=de&to=it&api-version=3.0&profanityAction=NoAction&textType=plain",
```

P.S. You exposed your API key above in the code. I recommend you delete this key and generate a new one.